# Redefined Global variable

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables

I'm a little Confused about this code result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g;
void afunc(int x)
{
     g = x; /* this sets the global to whatever x is */
}

int main(void)
{
    int g = 10;    /* Local g is now 10 */
    afunc(20); /* but this function will set it to 20 */
    printf("%d\n", g); /* so this will print "20" */

    return 0;
}
```

Why the result is 10 Not 20 ?

Comment: Because the "g" in main is different from the global "g".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `afunc` changes the global `g`, and `main` retains its local `g`.

Entering a function doesn’t swap its scope with the global scope. Each function* has its own scope.

<sub>* Among other things</sub>

Comment: @H2CO3: The C standard says the inner name *hides* the other name. It conceals it from view; there is no shadow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Although it usually means something different in OOP, is there a difference in C? ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) seems to think it’s okay, but then again, it’s not right all the time.)

Comment: Shadow is the term GCC uses, and the presence of the condition can be uncovered by passing in `-Wshadow` to the compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The local variable `g` shadows the global `g`.

If you want the `printf()` to show 20, you have to shadow your local variable `g` with a declaration of the global one you want to print:

```
int main(void)
{
    int g = 10;            /* Local g is now 10 */
    afunc(20);             /* Set global g to 20 */
    printf("%d\n", g);     /* Print local g, "10" */
    {
        extern int g;      /* Use global g */
        printf("%d\n", g); /* Print global g, "20" */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get rid of the `int` in

```
int g = 10;
```

then main will also be referring to the same global variable as `afunc` is.

This is called [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Answer (score 1):

Have NOT modified your code, but have adjusted your comments to indicate what the code is doing.  By the way, commenting your code is a really good idea and makes for better lab scores!! signed, A Former Graduate TA

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g;       /* define a global variable
void afunc(int x)
{
     g = x; /* this sets the global to whatever x is */
}

int main(void)
{
    int g = 10;    /* Define and set a Local g to 10 */
    afunc(20);     /* This function sets global x to 20 */
    printf("%d\n", g); /* this prints local g "10" */

    return 0;
}
```

To think about this "look-up" from main to global storage.  You see local g before global g, thus local g is used.

Answer (score 0):

In both the occasions, though the variable name appears to be same, they 2 are referring 2 different memory area. The variable g declared outside any function got stored in the RAM memory area, and the variable g declared inside main is got stored in stack area. So the invocation of **afunc()** is changing the variable g stored in RAM but again printing the variable g(stored in stack) which got declared locally.